# Selenium python can't detect popups?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I'm using Selenium Python to do something like a Robotic Process Automation. However, I am facing problems after logging in to the site, as three scenarios may arise:

1. The site goes to the main menu, and this is perfect
2. An alert appears [image: alert]
3. A popup appears [image]

I'm able to solve the alert scenario but unfortunately not the popup scenario... I tried multiple ways but for now my code looks like this:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
except (NoAlertPresentException, TimeoutException):
    try:
        driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#popup_0'))
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/a').click()
    except (NoSuchFrameException, TimeoutException):
        print('banana')
finally:
    print('OK...')
```

The Outer HTML of the popup:

```
<div id="popup_0" class="DIVPopup shadow " style="top: 103px; left: -73px; z-index: 100003; width: 380px; height: 175px; visibility: inherit; overflow: hidden;" arwindowid="0">
    <table id="DivTable" class="DIVPopup ResizablePopup" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
       <tbody>
          <tr class="DIVPopupTitleBar DIVDraggable">
             <td colspan="3" class="center" id="title_0" nowrap="" align="left">
                <div class="title">User - Error&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                <button type="button" class="Close  right" id="ardivpcl" title="Close" onclick="var target=FindClickedPopup('0', event); if(target){ target.OnCancel();target.stopBubbling(event);return false;}"></button>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td colspan="3" class="DIVPopupBodyNoBorder DIVPopupBodyBorder">
                <iframe id="1612895763753P" style="width: 100%; height: 154px;" src="https://.../arsys/resources/html/MessagePopup.html" frameborder="0">
                   #home
                     <html>
                         <head> ... </head>
                         <body class="PopupMsg" onload="onLoad()">
                             <div class="PopupMsgOuter" id="PopupMsgOuter">
                                 <table id="PopupMsgTbl" style="width: 379px; height: 118px;">
                                     <tbody>
                                         <tr>
                                         <td style="width:20%" valign="middle" align="center">
                                             <script>
                                                 document.write('<img src="../images/'+weArgs.image+'.gif">');
                                             </script><img src="../images/error.gif">
                                         </td>
                                         <td style="width:80%" valign="middle">
                                             <script>
                                                 if (weArgs.rtl) {
                                                     document.write('<div id="PopupMsgBox" class="PopupMsgBox" dir="ltr" style="right:60px">');
                                                 }
                                                 else {
                                                     document.write('<div id="PopupMsgBox" class="PopupMsgBox">');
                                                 }
                                                 if (weArgs.acc==1) 
                                                     document.write("<textarea rows=4 readonly=\"readonly\" style=\"width:250\">" + weArgs.msg.HTMLEncode() + "</textarea>");
                                                 else 
                                                     document.write(weArgs.msg.HTMLEncode().replace(/\n/g, "<br>"));
                                             </script>
                                             <div id="PopupMsgBox" class="PopupMsgBox" style="height: auto;">User is currently connected from another machine or incompatible session (ARERR 9084)<br></div>
                             </td></tr></tbody></table>
                             </div>
                             <div id="PopupMsgFooter" class="PopupMsgFooter"><a class="btn btn3d PopupBtn" href="#" arid="2" arwindowid="0">OK</a></div>
                             <script language="JavaScript">
                                 // Hang on to these elements for resizing
                                 var msgouter = document.getElementById("PopupMsgOuter");
                                 var msgtable = document.getElementById("PopupMsgTbl");
                                 var msgbox = document.getElementById("PopupMsgBox");
                                 var msgfooter = document.getElementById("PopupMsgFooter");
                                 function GlobalPopupKeyDown(ed) {
                                     if(weArgs.btn&2&&ed.key==13) {
                                         weCloseDialogue(windowID,{v:1});
                                         return true;
                                     }
                                     if((weArgs.btn&1||weArgs.btn==2)&&ed.key==27) {
                                         weCloseDialogue(windowID,{v:-1});
                                         return true;
                                     }
                                     return false;
                                 }
                                 function onLoad() {
                                     window.onbeforeunload=weOnUnload; 
                                     //dumpStack();
                                     window.focus();   
                                     PopupForm_Setup();
                                     if (weArgs.btn & 8)
                                         new PopupButton(windowID, 4, msgfooter, getLocalizedMessage("Yes"), function() { weCloseDialogue(windowID,{v:1});} );
                                     if (weArgs.btn & 4)
                                         new PopupButton(windowID, 3, msgfooter, getLocalizedMessage("No"), function() { weCloseDialogue(windowID,{v:0});} );
                                     if (weArgs.btn & 2)
                                         new PopupButton(windowID, 2, msgfooter, getLocalizedMessage("OK"), function() { weCloseDialogue(windowID,{v:1});} );
                                     if (weArgs.btn & 1)
                                         new PopupButton(windowID, 1, msgfooter, getLocalizedMessage("Cancel"), function() { weCloseDialogue(windowID,{v:-1});} );
                                     var dims = GetPopupDimensions();
                                     PopupResize(dims.width, dims.height);
                                     msgbox.focus(); //SW00258782: set initial focus to msgbox
                                     // notify external automation client that this popup is now really fully loaded
                                     notifyExternal(windowID);
                                 }
                             </script></body></html></iframe></td></tr></tbody></table>
                             <b class="rndfooter"><b class="rnd1"></b><b class="rnd2"></b><b class="rnd3"></b></b>
                             <div class="ResizeHandle  right" id="handle_0"></div>
 </div>
```

I am assuming that the "OK" (< div id = "PopupMsgFooter" class = "PopupMsgFooter" >< a class = "btn btn3d PopupBtn" href = "#" arid = "2" arwindowid = "0" > OK < /a >< /div >) button is a button but I am not really sure, and I think that is what I need to unveil to solve the problem. If you have advice on the quality of my code and how to fix it, I would be grateful.

Comment: The **User - Error** is a system error. AFAIK, Selenium won't be able to interact with it.

Comment: The real title is "The name of the application User - Error" in this case, does the rule remain?

Comment: From the visual representation the conclusion remains the same. Note: Possibly Winium (another blend of Selenium) can be used to interact with them.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but seeing the html, I don't think that's the case (?)

Comment: I did tests and I can close the window on the X button, but not on the OK button because I think it is not a button

Comment: That's precisely what I meant.

Comment: I'm talking about the X button of the popup not of the site.

Comment: show the whole source HTML there... can't see the opening <iframe> tag, or <html>(nested frame?)... you probably want to add a webdriverwait for expected condition of frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt... and target button by this attribute: arid="2"

Comment: You can find all the HTML in the question, including the tags <iframe> and <html>. I cannot use the attribute arid but I can use with By: id, class, xpath and link_text. I tried this code but it seems like it doesn't recognize the popup as an iframe because nothing was printed and it continues open... WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.LINK_TEXT, 'OK')));print('banana')driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'OK').click();print('apple')

Comment: Target via XPATH... something like "//a[@arid='2']".  To target the frame I think you need the name or src/href... current you don't show the beginning <iframe> tag, but you've used "#popup_0".  Show that part of the html... (really just include it all so we can troubleshoot properly)